# What is this hr = hr>=12 ? hr-12 : hr; means?

Tags: javascript

I am practicing this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations Clock tutorial.
Everything in the code is clear to me. 
Accept this `hr = hr>=12 ? hr-12 : hr;` is not clear me. May be it's a `if else` statement.

Can any explain what this code is doing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the ternary operator `(?:)`
Here is the simple explanation of what is being done here:

```
if(hr>=12)
{
    hr=hr-12;
}
//or else hr will have its same value
```

Answer (score 4):

its called Ternary operation

It means

```
if(hr>=12)
 hr=hr-12;
else
 hr=hr;
```

the following is **enough**

```
if(hr>=12)
     hr=hr-12;
```

Comment: I agree , its just to explain the statment

Answer (score 4):

```
if (hr >= 12) {
   hr = hr - 12;
}
```

if `hr` does not meet that criteria `hr` should effectively be left untouched.

Answer (score 3):

It's a ternary operator, of the form:

```
condition ? if_true | if_false
```

If you add more brackets for readibility, it can become:

```
hr = ( (hr >= 12) ? (hr - 12) : hr )
```

That is, if more than 12, subtract 12, and store back to hr.

Answer (score 2):

`hr= hr>=12 ? hr-12 : hr;` is same to `if( hr >= 12 ) hr = hr-12 else hr = hr;`

the `bool ? expr_a : expr_b` is a operator that when `bool` is true, expr_a is evaluated and its value will be used as the whole expr's value, otherwise the expr_b will be.

Answer (score 2):

It means:

```
if(hr>=12)
{
  hr = hr - 12;
}
```

Generally:

```
x= condition ? y : z
```

if condition is true, then `x = y`, else `x = z`

Answer (score 2):

It has same effect as this:

```
hr %= 12;   //equivalent to -> hr = hr>=12 ? hr-12 : hr;
```

Comment: That's actually brilliant in this application. Except that it doesn't do exactly this - for when hr=25, your option gives 1 while his gives 13, so it's not exactly equivalent.

Comment: @qdot By 'same effect', I meant *in this context* it has same effect, where `hr` is hours, and can't have values outside of [0,23] range.

Comment: Or it misses the potential for validity check - if after this operation it doesn't fit in the [0,11] range, then it's clearly invalid. Your approach allows large positive integers to slip through.

Comment: @qdot C'mon dude, for what 'validity' are you thinking about? Did you see the example-> `var hr = now.getHours();`, where `now` is `Date` object. link-> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations

Comment: yeah, I saw the example, but it's clearly meant as something of an educational value - there is no need to be angry about it, your comment is clearly brilliant in *this* application, but it's clearly not equivalent - sometimes you can use this for sanitizing input values from a form, and then check whether it fits the [0,11] range - in which case your answer is not equivalent. There is nothing improper about it in this context, but it's definitely not *equivalent*

Comment: @qdot Yes, I agree with `Ainstein`, that `Everything Is Relative`,and what is `true` in current context, can be `false` in other context :).

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).